# Transpose in Spark scala logic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, analytics

I have below dataframe in spark scala dataframe:

```
-------------
a | b| c| d |
-------------
1 | 2| 3 | 4 |
5 | 6| 7 | 8 |
9 | 10| 11 | 12 |
13 | 14| 15 | 16 |
```

From my code it becomes a map of every rows and,code I try is:

```
df.select(map(df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c),col(c))):_*).as("map"))
Map(String-> String) with 4 records only
Map(a->1,b->2,c->3,d->4)
Map(a->5,b->6,c->7,d->8)
Map(a->9,b->10,c->11,d->12)
Map(a->13,b->14,c->15,d->16)
```

But I wanted to change like below:

```
a->1
b->2 
c->3
d->4
a->5
b->6 
c->7
d->8
a->9
b->10 
c->11
d->12
a->13
b->14
c->15
d->16
```

Any suggestion to change/add code to get desired result, I think it should be any transpose logic I am kind of new in scala .

Comment: map can not store duplicate columns,  how you want to handle this ?

Comment: We can create 2 columns out of it k,v from the map and remove duplicate on row basis and can store in a file

Comment: Do you want two columns k, v ?

Comment: yes, k can be repeat  but combination of k,v can be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` to explode map data.Try below code.

```
df.select(map(df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c),col(c))):_*).as("map"))
.select(explode($"map"))
.show(false)
```

Without `map` used `array`

```
val colExpr = array(
    df
    .columns
    .flatMap(c => Seq(struct(lit(c).as("key"),col(c).as("value")).as("map"))):_*
).as("map")
```

```
df
.select(colExpr)
.select(explode($"map").as("map"))
.select($"map.*").show(false)
```

Comment: Great, is there a way I can retain duplicate records as well I mean instead of map can we implement list as well