# Convert Array to Columns and replace values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data of following format:

```
+-----+---------------+
| name|           Data|
+-----+---------------+
|Alpha|      [A, B, C]|
| Beta|   [A, B, C, D]|
|Gamma|[A, B, C, D, E]|
+-----+---------------+
```

How to transform it into ?

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name|   A|    B|    C|    D|    E|
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Alpha|   1|    1|    1|    0|    0|
| Beta|   1|    1|    1|    1|    0|
|Gamma|   1|    1|    1|    1|    1|
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Thanks to @Jarrod Baker for help in similar [transformation earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516206/spark-transform-array-to-column-with-size-of-array-using-map-iterable)

Here is the code that i have:

```
val df = Seq(
      ("Alpha", Array("A", "B", "C")),
      ("Beta", Array("A", "B", "C", "D")),
      ("Gamma", Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")),
).toDF("name", "Data")
df.show()

val arrayDataSize = df.withColumn("arr_size", size(col("Data"))).agg(max("arr_size") as "maxSize") 

val newDF = df.select(($"name") +: (0 until arrayDataSize.first.getInt(0)).map(i => {($"Data") (i).contains("A").alias("A") }): _*)

newDF.show()
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name|   A|    A|    A|    A|    A|
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Alpha|true|false|false| null| null|
| Beta|true|false|false|false| null|
|Gamma|true|false|false|false|false|
+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854310/transpose-in-spark-scala-logic) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803305/scala-explode-method-cartesian-product-multiple-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RelationalGroupedDataset`'s `pivot` method to achieve what you want. To create such a Dataset, you need to use `groupBy` on a Dataset.

It would look something like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("Alpha", Seq("A", "B", "C")),
  ("Beta", Seq("A", "B", "C", "D")),
  ("Gamma", Seq("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
).toDF("name", "Data")

val output = df
  .select(df("name"), explode(col("Data")).alias("Data"))
  .groupBy("name")
  .pivot("Data")
  .count()

output.show()
+-----+---+---+---+----+----+
| name|  A|  B|  C|   D|   E|
+-----+---+---+---+----+----+
| Beta|  1|  1|  1|   1|null|
|Gamma|  1|  1|  1|   1|   1|
|Alpha|  1|  1|  1|null|null|
+-----+---+---+---+----+----+
```

As you can see, we're first `explode`-ing our Sequences into separate rows. This allows us to treat each element in each sequence as a separate "entity".

Then, we're using `groupBy` to get our `RelationalGroupedDataset`, after which we `pivot` and `count` the occurences.